# Mars exploration rover programming language

Tags: java, embedded

I have read that Java was used extensively for the MER project (i.e. Spirit and Opportunity - those little robots scurrying around Mars).

I have read some contradicting information. One article I read (offline) said Java was used for image viewing. Wikipedia said something similar.
However [this article](http://java.sys-con.com/node/39220) says Java was used in (quote):

> controlling the Rovers' operating system.

If anyone knows how extesnively Java was used in the Mars rovers I would very much like to know.

Secondly, why was Java chosen for its role? I would have guessed the first choice for the controls would be Ada (please don't take that as an insult to Java).

Comment: wasnt there a contest before? may because java runs in VM - so you can shut it down from earth when somethings wrong...

Comment: Java gives no advantage whatsoever for such an application. Unless you have some 1st source article by NASA stating that Java was used, I would dismiss this as a false rumour. I would suspect that they are using either Ada or C.

Comment: @Lundin: Or Forth.  There's quite a bit of Forth in NASA work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project to evaluate Java for flight in general, but it wasn't flown on those MER rovers, and as far as I can see it's not planned to be used in flight for future rovers either.

The definitive refererence appears to be *MER Flight Software Baseline Architecture and Design Document* by Joseph F. Snyder, Edwin P. Kan, the MER FSW Team.  But I can't locate a viewable copy.  Nevertheless there's plenty of information about the design in review documents, for example, *[An Overview of the Mars Exploration Rovers Flight Software](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/37499/1/05-0539.pdf)* by Glenn E. Reeves:

> The Flight Software is coded primarily
>   in ANSI C, with some targeted assembly
>   code and some C++. The size of the
>   system, in source lines of code
>   (SLOC), is [300K] but this value does
>   not include the operating system.

The operating system is Wind River's VxWorks.

Answer (score 1):

"I have read that Java was used extensively for the MER project (i.e. Spirit and Opportunity - those little robots scurrying around Mars)."

NASA is too conservative to switch to Java, as C (and C++) has proven adequate to the task for 20+ years, since Mars Pathfinder used VXworks/C on the lander software in 1997.
Mars 2020 is the last JPL spacecraft to use that same successful combination.
Java is rarely used in real-time systems, and mostly in business software.

"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: I'm late to the party, as usual, but I believe Java's licensing states it must not be used for mission critical software. While there are other variants of Java, IE Android, perhaps this is another reason Java hasn't been used on Mars. Oracle's licensing for Java changed in 2019, so perhaps current versions aren't limited in this way.

Answer (score 0):

"The Flight Software is coded primarily in ANSI C, with some targeted assembly code and some C++. The size of the system, in source lines of code (SLOC), is [300K] but this value does not include the operating system"

So, no Java!

Reference:
An Overview of the Mars Exploration Rovers Flight Software
Glenn E. Reeves
MER Flight Software Architect
Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology